# Showing two Laurent polynomials are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I have a question about two Laurent polynomials in $K[X^{\pm 1}]$, $K$ a field.

> Is it true that $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^i X^{i-2j+1}$ is equal to $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^i X^{2j-i-1}$?

It seems to work for all the examples I try, but I can't find a proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the change of index : $ k=i-j+1 $, gives : $$ \sum_{j=1}^{i}{X^{i-2j+1}}=\sum_{k=1}^{i}{X^{i-2(i-k+1)+1}}=\sum_{k=1}^{i}{X^{2k-i-1}} $$

Answer (score 0):

It's the same, matching the left side of the expression with index $1$ to right side of the expression with index $i$, and match the left side of the expression with index $i$ to right side of the expression of index $i$. Basically there's a bijection and the summation was the same.